# Method of an abstract class doesn't use a property, that was declared by derived class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently trying to extend my own little framework for WordPress-themes by a "notification" module. This is not supposed to replace exceptions - even though the concept might be similar. Since I am trying to write the framework object-oriented and am still new to this whole concept, I ran into a problem which I can't figure out how to solve.

**The following code** declares an abstract notification class with a constructor requesting notification-title and -message. Afterwards, the constructor adds the member method `show()` to the wordpress action stack. Since the user and the rest of the framework-code should not pass the type of the notification as a parameter, I created four classes for every notification type, extending the notification class. Those child classes don't need to overwrite the whole method of showing the notification, they only need to change the `type` property of the class they are extending. The base functionality works, so the notifications are shown on my page.

**The problem is:** The `type` property is empty, when `show()` is called on the page-footer by WordPress' `do_action( 'ease_notifications' );`. I found out, that propertys are not set before the constructor is called (which really makes sense somehow...). Anyway, the method using the `type` property is `show()`, and this method is called long after the class has been constructed. So theoretically, the property should have been set by then. Can you explain to me why it isn't?

```
abstract class EaseNotification
{
    private $type;
    private $title;
    private $message;

    public function __construct( $title, $message )
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->message = $message;
        add_action( 'ease_notifications', array(&$this, 'show') );
    }

    public function show()
    {
        echo '<div class="ease-notification type-' . $this->type . '">'
           . '<span class="ease-notification-title">' . $this->title . '</span>'
           . '<p class="ease-notification-body">' . $this->message . '</p>'
           . '</div>';
    }
}

class EaseError extends EaseNotification { private $type = "error"; }
class EaseWarning extends EaseNotification { private $type = "warning"; }
class EaseInformation extends EaseNotification { private $type = "information"; }
class EaseConfirmation extends EaseNotification { private $type = "confirmation"; }
```

Usage of the notification class:

```
require_once( 'class.easenotification.php' );

new EaseConfirmation( 'Hurray', 'It works, so you can be very happy.' );
```

Comment: problem with `(new EaseConfirmation(.......))->show()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$type` property in your `EaseNotification` class is not the same as the `$type` property in your `EaseConfirmation` class. You have declared them private so both have the scope / visibility of the class they are declared in only.

There are a few ways you can solve that, assuming that you want one `$type` variable only.

For example:

- Declare the property `protected` instead of private and don't declare the property in the extended class. Instead, set the value in the constructor of the child classes. A `protected` property of the parent class is visible in the child classes.
- Add a (public or protected...) getter and setter method in your `EaseNotification` class so that you can access the property from the extended classes. You also should remove the property declaration from the child classes as you won't be using that property any more.

Comment: sounds like declaration of private things in abstract class should throw some STRICT errors?

Comment: @M0rtiis No, that should be no problem, but you would need visible getters / setters to access it.

Comment: but i think it may be (should) thrown some stricts. not very clear to declare private in abstract. php? mean no clear what is first. if abstaract - then no sense in private there. if private - damn, then its should be not so private

Comment: @M0rtiis It really doesn't :-) And there is no reason to either, there is nothing wrong about a private property in an abstract class.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand the problem and both your solutions - but one thing I am curious about; wouldn't declaring a constructor on my derived classes overwrite the constructor of the parent class? I really want to have this stay the same for all the derived classes. I know that you can call the parent-constructor there, but then I have to redefine the arguments ($title and $message) for all constructors in the derived classes and hand them over to the parent constructor.

Comment: @JonathanWeber Yes it would. In that case you should add a getter and setter and use these everywhere. And you really need to remove the property declarations from your child classes as that is what will be used when you declare a child class.

Comment: Thank you - that helped a lot and now it is working. For others who are stumbeling over the same question:

1. I added `$this->setType();` to the constructor of the parent class.
2. I added `protected function setType() { $this->type = "notification"; }` to the parent class.
3. I overwrite this function in derived classes, changing "notification" to my custom notification type.
4. I changed `private $type;` to `protected $type;` in the parent class.
5. I removed the `private $type = "error";` from all derived classes.

Please let me now if I misunderstood your concept.